# Android, Possible to add a native header for webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'd like to add a native header to the webview.

When you scroll the webview, header also scrolls.

Google doesn't know the answer to this..

Answer (score 0):

You may try to define your layout with the webview and your header view. 
The WebView class will be extended to override the method [onScrollChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).
There you may define the logic to scroll the header view based on internal webview content scroll.

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView{
    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged (int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt){
         //TODO Scroll Header view based on current t scroll vertical origin
    }
}
```